# CoordinatorLayout support v24.1.0 issue

Tags: android

I have just updated android support libs to 24.1.0 and I have the following issue:

```
error inflate CoordinatorLayout... 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

but my style.xml is like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 07/22/2016**

Fixed in 24.1.1

Comment: Is your coordinator layout using a different them than AppTheme? Maybe, the activity is using a different theme.. Check your manifest and check also if you are not using a different theme for specific Activities

Comment: Are you using the Theme.AppCompat style for every case or do you have other styles defined for certain configurations (e.g. "values-v24")? Are your activities extending from the AppCompatActivity class?

Comment: The CoordinateLayout don't use a different theme, I'm using Theme.AppCompat style for every case and all my activities are extending from the AppCompatActivity class. Works with support 24.0.0 but not with 24.1.0 ...

Comment: This bug is tracked in AOSP: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216437