# com.android.support:design:24.1.0 causes error "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme"

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I just updated from design:24.0.0 to design:24.1.0 and now I'm getting the following error anytime any design widget gets inflated:

"You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library"

I've been trying to debug the issue and here are some things to note and things I've done:

- Performed a clean build (Cleared gradle and maven caches, stopped gradle daemom, reboot)
- tried on a different computer (same error)
- rolling back to design:24.0.0 works fine

I have debugged to the exception in "ThemeUtils.java" and I don't understand how it is possible that I'm getting the error

[image]

This is my debug session... note the following (from the watches):

- android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.colorPrimary and APPCOMPAT_CHECK_ATTRS[0] SHOULD be EQUAL
- The last line of the watches (context.obtainStyled.....hasValue = true) indicate that my context DOES use a Theme.AppCompat theme
- When I control+click on "android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.colorPrimary", it shows me the "... colorPrimary = 0x7f0100d6;" (which is decimal: 2130772182)

So here are the questions:

- How is it possible that the [0] value in the "static final int[] APPCOMPAT_CHECK_ATTRS" does not equal to "android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.colorPrimary"?
- How can I fix this? (help)

Comment: Could you explain why you absolutely need 24.1.0? Have you filed a bug report?

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463764/coordinatorlayout-support-v24-1-0-issue

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the response.... We don't absolutely need to move to 24.1.0, but I would like to know what changed int 24.1.0 to break our app, plus if there is an issue with the design library, I'll file a report (I thought I would post the question here first).  I looked at the other issue... we may be having the same issue... don't know for sure.

Comment: This bug is tracked in AOSP: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216437

Comment: @TalkLittle This sounds like it could be the issue

Comment: @JeffCampbell Do you have any code you can share? This way we can try to reproduce. I'm not able to reproduce the issue just by inflating a design widget